# Button link not working in SendGrid email on Apple Mail

Tags: html, email, sendgrid, apple-mail

I have created HTML and converted the inline to render with most email clients through a SendGrid template. However there is one element, a button and link that fail to render in Apple Mail. The button simply does not work. It is working and goes through to the link in GMail and other clients.

I have tried to use existing code to render the button, however it has not made any difference. Wondering if anyone else has had this problem with Apple Mail.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="module" data-role="module-button" data-type="button" role="module" style="table-layout: fixed;box-sizing: border-box;border-collapse: collapse;" width="100%"><tbody style="box-sizing: border-box;"><tr style="box-sizing: border-box;page-break-inside: avoid;"><td align="center" class="outer-td" style="padding: 0px 0px 45px 0px;box-sizing: border-box;"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="button-css__deep-table___2OZyb wrapper-mobile" style="text-align: center;box-sizing: border-box;border-collapse: collapse;"><tbody style="box-sizing: border-box;"><tr style="box-sizing: border-box;page-break-inside: avoid;"><td align="center" bgcolor="#F5A623" class="inner-td" style="border-radius: 6px;font-size: 16px;text-align: center;background-color: inherit;box-sizing: border-box;"><a style="background-color: #F5A623;border: 1px solid #333333;border-color: #F5A623;border-radius: 3px;border-width: 1px;color: #ffffff;display: inline-block;font-family: helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 16px;font-weight: normal;letter-spacing: 0px;line-height: 16px;padding: 15px 75px 15px 75px;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;box-sizing: border-box;-webkit-text-decoration-skip: objects;" href="{{{c2a_link}}}" target="_blank">{{c2a_button}}</a></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Define "does not work". Is it not showing up at all? Is it showing up but not clickable?

Comment: Hi Ceejayoz, the button renders correctly as expected, it is simply not clickable in Apple Mail client. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved this, it was simply that the link was 'www.example.com' whereas it needs to strictly be 'http://www.example.com' for the Apple Mail client to recognise the button link.
Thanks